# REGEX - HTML to Shortcode breaking when inner content has line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

I have created a simple **wrapper shortcode** in my wordpress theme.

And am using `ed.onBeforeSetContent` and `ed.onPostProcess` to switch back and forth from

**shortcode** `[wrap vars="whatever"]my cool content[/wrap]` in text view to

**html** `<div class="wrap">my cool content</div>` in visual view

This works great with this code.

```
_get_wrap : function(co) {
    return co.content.replace(/\<div(.*?)?\>(?:(.+?)?\<\/div\>)?/g, function(a,b,c) {               
        var arr = b.replace(/['"]/g,'').split(' ');
        var params = new Object();
        for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var p = arr[i].split('=');
            params[p[0]] = p[1];
        }
        if ( params['class'] == "wrap" )
            return '[wrap'+b+']'+c+'[/wrap]';
        return a;
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, if there is a `return` or `new line` within the content in between the opening and closing shortcode, it fails

How can I keep the `c` content intact with the code above when there are line breaks?

Comment: This is really quite difficult to take in. Perhaps consider reformatting your question so it's easy for your peers to read.

Comment: I agree with @simonmorley.  I believe I answered the question correctly below, but you would have been better of boiling this question down to a very simple example that demonstrates the problem (not matching across newlines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` wildcard does NOT match newlines.  To match newlines, you have to use the following: `[^]`:

```
_get_wrap : function(co) {
    return co.content.replace(/\<div([^]*?)?\>(?:([^]+?)?\<\/div\>)?/g, function(a,b,c) {               
        var arr = b.replace(/['"]/g,'').split(' ');
        var params = new Object();
        for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var p = arr[i].split('=');
            params[p[0]] = p[1];
        }
        if ( params['class'] == "wrap" )
            return '[wrap'+b+']'+c+'[/wrap]';
        return a;
    });
}
```